# Constant expression contains invalid operations and Expression is not allowed as default value errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.7 and I am trying to specify validation rules that when a user is updating their email the email must be unique BUT if its the same email for the current user ignore this rule. I am trying to pass the user id to the rule but its not working

The errors I am getting :

> Constant expression contains invalid operations
>
> Expression is not allowed as default value

```
private $updateValidationRules =
 [
    'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email,'."$this->id"],
    'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't use a variable in a property declaration.  If this is a model, the id might not be known until long after this class is instantiated

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 'email' => [
        'required','string', 'email', 'max:255',
        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
    ],
```